# HTML <input type="file"... check filesize with Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'd like to know how to use the JavaScript `onChange` event on `<input type="file"...`  so that when a user selected files, `onChange` will call Flash to return the file's size and decide what to do next.

2nd. How to use JavaScript to exclude this check, if the browser doesn't have Flash.

Comment: Slightly OT (hence commenting, not answering), but you might also check to see if the user's browser supports the new File API stuff from the W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) and, if so, use that, only falling back to Flash if you have to. Theres an example of using the File API here on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload). You wouldn't need all of that code, because you're not actually reading the file contents, just checking the size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a part of FancyUpload project - http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/. This control has a good documentation.
Alternatively I use the client ActiveX

```
var objFileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var strFilename = document.upload.file.value;
var resFile = objFileSystem.getFile(strFilename);
var intSize = resFile.size;
```

Check the [Cross Browser Flash Detection in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript) for 2nd issue