# How do i get the full path of the file in Firefox

Tags: javascript

How do i get the full path of the file in Firefox with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @close voters: The linked "duplicate" seems to me to be asking about getting the full path *server-side*, in the submitted form. (When he says "...if we submit a file..." that's sounding server-side to me.) This is a client-side question.

Comment: @close voters (again, sorry): And in particular, if you look at the accepted answer, the workaround from "kdh" in the linked article (no longer on the same page as was linked, more comments have been added) is a solution to ensure that the full path is sent to the *server*.

Comment: There's no real question in here. What 'file' is under discussion?

Comment: @bmargulies: Very good point, I assumed he meant from an `input type="file"`, but that was an assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't, for security reasons.

However, the new/upcoming [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) allows you to do just about everything you might want to do by getting the file's full path, without giving you the file's full path. You can read the file (yes, client-side), get a data-URI for it, etc. Example and details in [this other question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload).

Comment: J. Maybe you want to post this answer on [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81180/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-html-input-form-in-firefox-3), because this question will probably get deleted.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. I don't read that as a duplicate, I'll comment on the question to explain.