# Reading local files with <input type="file">?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, file-upload, canvas

I have seen some demos where mozilla guys dropped a photo into a dropbox and then edited it locally in the browser. But now i cannot find out the demo and i need to load images to my html, then edit them with canvas element, then upload them to server. I think there is a way of doing this but i cannot find any good explanation.
Basically i need to take a picture on my clients computer and insert it into a canvas element without touching the server.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) from the W3C (which Mozilla had a lot to do with). I've done a couple of File API examples in answers to other StackOverflow questions that may be useful:

- [HTML5 File API read as text and binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509)
- [Get Image dimensions using Javascript during file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063)
- [How to know the size of the image to be uploaded with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152365/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-image-to-be-uploaded-with-javascript/4152398#4152398)

That second one, in particular, shows loading a local image file into an `img` element, which you could readily use with a `canvas`.

If you want the drag-and-drop aspect, you might also check out the HTML5 [Drag and Drop stuff](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html); related article: *[Google Turns to HTML5 for Gmail’s New Drag-and-Drop Attachments](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/04/google-turns-to-html5-for-gmails-new-drag-and-drop-attachments/)*.