# FileReader returns "undefined". Why?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

Can anyone figure out why this declaration of a FileReader object returns undefined?

```
console.log("this is f " + f);
```

console.log(f);

```
var reader = new FileReader(); 
var ref = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
console.log(ref);
console.log("the reader object is " + reader.length);//why does reader not have a length       property?
```

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trkkazulu/6bV63/

Thanks,

J. Wells

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The downvotes seem a bit harsh to me, Jair-Rohm is clearly making an effort.

Answer (score 3):

[`FileReader` doesn't *have* a `length` property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader) You might want [`Blob#size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-size) (`File` — your `f` is a `File` instance — inherits from `Blob`).

[Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152365/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-image-to-be-uploaded-with-javascript/4152398#4152398) to an SO answer I did a while ago showing the size of a file using the File API, if that's what you're trying to get.

Comment: Thanks! What i'm ultimately trying to get is a reference to an audio file that can be used by a "decode" function that i have. This fileReader object is just being used right now to sort the different audio formats for different decoders.

Comment: I've changed "length" to "size" and the FileReader object still comes back as "undefined" and its size property doesn't exist. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Jair-RohmParkerWells: Look at the answer again: The `size` property isn't on `FileReader`, it's on `Blob` (and inherited by `File`). So not `reader`, but `f`. More likely, though, given your comment above you probably want to respond to the `load` event and look at the data in the `ArrayBuffer` in [`reader.result`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-result). [Here's another SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509) I've done showing actually getting the content of the file (you're interested in the "binary" bit).

Comment: Ok, i moved my call for the reader object's size into the reader.onload() block. Now i get a size by calling 'size' on the 'file' parameter that i'm passing to reader.onload. Ok, cool. Still, my variable "stuff" comes back "undefined".

Comment: @Jair-RohmParkerWells: There's no `stuff` variable in your question. (Questions shouldn't rely on linked-only content -- er, linked off-site that is, it's fine to rely on SO content.) But I think if you read through the two examples I've linked, particularly the second one, you'll get there.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder Very cool. Thanks. I liked to a JsFiddle of my project. I'll look at the SO that you sent. Thanks!

Comment: this is "stuff"` if(extension === "amr") {
 40         var stuff = e.target.result;
 41         console.log("stuff is " + stuff.size + " bytes");
 42         console.log(stuff);
 43` The funny thing is that 'stuff.size' comes back 'undefined' the call to "console.log(stuff)" prints the binary file out. What's up?

Comment: @Jair-RohmParkerWells: Why are you looking at `e.target.result`? Sorry, but I don't think I can help you any further. Walk through the working examples I've provided, step by step, and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder I'll work through the examples you've sent. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.