# What do .files actually do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I see people using the `.files` extension like this:

```
var selectedElement = document.getElementById(id).files[0];
```

I only know it is part of the DOM. I've tried to search the internet to find a reference about what this does, but I can't find any. Can you guys explain or present more information about this?

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which is available in [all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) except IE9 and earlier. `files` is a [`FileList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) of the file(s) selected by the user in the `input[type=file]` element you're referencing via the `id` in your `id` variable.

Each entry in the `FileList` is a [`File`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-file), which gives you the name of the file (without path information) and which can be used for accessing the files.

[Here is a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fileapi) of questions and answers about the File API here on SO.

Here are three of my answers on Stack Overflow demonstrating various ways to use the File API:

- [get image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063)
- [get file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152365/how-to-know-the-size-of-the-image-to-be-uploaded-with-javascript/4152398#4152398)
- [read as text vs. binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146483/html5-file-api-read-as-text-and-binary/3146509#3146509)