# Preview Image before uploading file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have got one problem by uploading file. I created an aspx file in asp.net then I added a fileupload control and image control. I want to show preview image in image control before uploading. I created a following script.

```
<img id="Image" src="" alt="" />
            <br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" onchange="document.getElementById('Image').src = 'file:///' + this.value;alert('file:///' + this.value);" />
```

It is not work in every browser. How could I do that?

Comment: Please give me reason why you give me vote down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Modal PopUp [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/05/09/may-2011-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx) This is an example on fileupload control. With few tweaks you can modify it to suit your need.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, for security reasons the full path of the file isn't made available to your script (if it were, you'd have to perform transformations on it to use it as a URL).

On some modern browsers, you could use the new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to actually read the image data and show it on the page. I've previously written [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063) here on SO shows how to do that (in that case, so we can find the image dimensions).

But other than that, you have to assume the user has a means of seeing what image they've chosen, aside from your web page.

Comment: I asked the same question before a month but found not the right solution. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MVC, you might try this approach below. It also use button for uploading image:

**Model:**

```
[Display(Name = "Photo")]
public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }

[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
<div>
    @if (Model.ImageData == null)
    {
        <img id="myImage" class="photo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/no_photo.png")" />
    }
    else
    {
        <img id="myImage" class="photo" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "YourController", new { Model.ID })" />
    }
        <label for="myInput" class="custom-file-upload"></label>
        <input type='file' id="myInput" name="image" />
</div>

<script>
    //Preview & Update an image before it is uploaded
    function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#myImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $("#myInput").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

**Css:**

```
/*For photo/image upload operations */
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 5.25em;
    margin-left:200px;
}

.photo{
    width: 7em; 
    height: 9em; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197); 
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; 
    float:right;
}

   <br/>
```

**Controller:**

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int id)
{
    var dataContext = repository.Participants.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id);
    if (dataContext != null)
    {
        return File(dataContext.ImageData, dataContext.ImageMimeType);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude = null)] Student student, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                    
                if (image != null)
                {
                    student.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                    student.ImageData = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                    image.InputStream.Read(participant.ImageData, 0, image.ContentLength);
                }

                repository.SaveStudent(student);
………
```