# Display Chosen Image From FileUpload before upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm using the control FileUpload to choose an image and upload but now I want to display a preview of the chosen image before saving the image, just to give the user an output of the chosen image.

I googled but could not find an answer for that.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why not create a PictureBox and set the property Image to the selected file path? You may then create a button "Confirm" that processes the upload on its click. Have a great day :)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1463798.aspx/1

Comment: If you use MVC, you might try method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092723/preview-image-before-uploading-file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have to upload the image to your server to you can display(serve) it.
I did some searching, and found this question: [How to show local picture in web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908171/how-to-show-local-picture-in-web-page) - and I was thinking, if you have the local path of the image, why not use some ajax to pop the url in a simple img tag.

However, you can't even link to a local image anymore, due to security. So for your application to show a preview of the image you would have to first have the image to display it, and the upload would have to occur first.