# How to save image in database and display it into Views in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a table like following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Movies] (
[fname] NVARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[lname] NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
[MoviePoster] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
```

how to save image to movie poster  field and how to view it

Comment: You might have a look at my answers regarding to this issue on [How to display images in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651531/how-to-display-images-in-mvc/30653266#30653266) and [Preview Image before uploading file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092723/preview-image-before-uploading-file/29036150#29036150).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Creat an "Images" folder in Solution explorer.
2. Create an ADO.NET Entity Data Model (in this example is "Database1Entities")

**Home Controller**

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;

 namespace test2.Controllers
 {
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index()
   {
   return View();
  }

 public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
 {   

 if (file != null)
{
    Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
    string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string physicalPath =Server.MapPath("~/images/"+ ImageName);

    // save image in folder
    file.SaveAs(physicalPath);

    //save new record in database
    tblA newRecord = new tblA();
    newRecord.fname = Request.Form["fname"];
    newRecord.lname = Request.Form["lname"];
    newRecord.MoviePoster = ImageName;
    db.tblAs.Add(newRecord);
    db.SaveChanges();

}
//Display records
return RedirectToAction("../home/Display/");
}

public ActionResult Display()
{
  return View();
 }
 }
 }
```

**Index View**

```
@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
 <div>
 First name<br />
@Html.TextBox("fname") <br />
Last name<br />
@Html.TextBox("lname") <br />
Image<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
</div>    
}
```

**DisplayView**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Display";
}

@{
test2.Database1Entities db = new test2.Database1Entities();
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in db.tblAs)
{
    <tr>
        <td><img src="~/images/@item.imageUrl" width="100" height="100" />             </td>
        <td>@item.fname</td>
        <td>@item.lname</td>
    </tr>
 }
  </tbody>
 </table>
}
```

The OutPut will be a table with viewed image from the database

Answer (score 1):

```
  [MoviePoster]      [varbinary](max) NULL
```

-- You have to insert image as a BLOB
-- Insert blob script :

```
INSERT INTO [Movies](MoviePoster) 
VALUES (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'your img url', SINGLE_BLOB))
```

--Display image in views:

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, <--data from db-->' />
```

Answer (score 1):

How about saving movie poster on your server let's say:

```
/content/images/movieposters/thearrival.jpg
```

and storing in `MoviePoster` field only the filename  `thearrival.jpg`

I personally prefer this approach because if let's say your database will grow and you will have more visitors ...well, you will be able to move all your movie posters to a different server and free up a lot of load from application server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can store the image on Db as well. You don't need to keep it on the server as a file if you don't want to (if you have lots of movies it would be a problem to manage).

If you are using SQL Server there is a "image" data type. If you are using MySql you should use BLOB.

I am using MVC, so:

The Model (partial code) (while in SqlServer you will declare image, inside the model the type will be byte[]:

```
public byte[] PersonImage { get; set; }
```

Inside the same model you are going to need a method to retrieve the path:

```
public string GetPicture()
    {
        if (PersonImage == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var base64Image = System.Convert.ToBase64String(PersonImage);
        return $"data:{ImageContentType};base64,{base64Image}";
    }
```

The create action inside the controller (The action declaration will need to receive an IFormFile PersonImage), on my case I am handling the image upload on the register action of my controller (Some of the controller code has been taken off to be more concise):

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, Client client, Employee employee, Person person, IFormFile PersonImage, string returnUrl = null)

 if (PersonImage != null)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await PersonImage.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    person.PersonImage = stream.ToArray();
                    person.ImageContentType = PersonImage.ContentType;
                }
            }
 _context.Add(person);
 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And now the view, you need to add the enctype to the form:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Create a new account.</h2>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@person.PersonImage" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="@person.PersonImage" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@person.PersonImage" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

Again, I took off most of the code to get a better and concise example. I had a hard time to find this when I was trying to put some images to the Db.

Answer (score 0):

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmployee(HttpPostedFileBase file)
       {   
       using(DbEntities DB = new DbEntities())
         { 
            TblImage tblimg=new TblImage();
            if (file != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/EmployeeProfileImage/" + fileName));    
                tblimg.image = "~/Data/EmployeeProfileImage/" + fileName;

            }
          DB.TblImages.Add(tblimg);
          DB.SaveChanges(); 
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<link href="~/bootstrapp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrapp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
    }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Candidate", FormMethod.Post,
                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
<div class="container">    
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="2" style="width:800px;height:50px">candidate</td></tr>
        <tr><td>@*<label>Id</label><input type="number" name="candidateID" />*@</td></tr>
           <tr>           
            <td style ="width:10px;height:10px">                
                <label>Name</label>    <input type="text" name="Name" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:80px;height:50px"><label>Binary Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" style="width: 100%;" /> <br />       
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Address</label> <input type="text" name="address" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Path Image</label> <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2" style="width: 100%;" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>JobProfile</label>   <input type="text" name="JobProfile" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Email</label>  <input type="text" name="email" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
    <label>Phone No.</label> <input type="number" name="phone" />
</td><td ><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
}
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Candidate/detail.cshtml")



DETAIL



@*@model List< angularmvcdemo.CandidateDetail>*@
@using angularmvcdemo.Models;



<link href="~/bootstrapp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrapp/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 5px;
    }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>

@{
    modeldataEntities db = new modeldataEntities();
    //angularmvcdemo.modeldataEntities db = new angularmvcdemo.modeldataEntities();


}
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="width:800px;height:50px">candidate</td></tr>
    @foreach(var detail in db.CandidateDetails){   
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10px;height:10px">
            <label>Name</label>@detail.Name
            @*<input type="text" name="Name" />*@ </td>
        <td> binary image
            @if (detail.BinaryPhoto != null)
            { var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(detail.BinaryPhoto);
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
<img src='@imgsrc' style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            }
            else { <img src="~/img/avatar-default.jpg" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />   }        </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Address</label>     @detail.address       </td>
        <td><label>path image</label>
            @if(@detail.PathPhoto!=null){        <img src="@detail.PathPhoto" width="100" height="100" />
            }else{ <img src="~/img/avatar-default.jpg" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />           }       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>JobProfile</label>@detail.JobProfile </td>
        <td>
            <label>Email</label>          @detail.email </td>
    </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><label>Phone No.</label>
@detail.phone</td><</tr>
    }
</table>
```