# Creating image object with local image using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create image object when user selecting a file from html page.

How can i create image object for dynamic images. Can anybody share me the sample snippet .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to put some more effort in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically:

- You can create an `img` element like any other element: [`createElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-2141741547). (There's also `new Image()` which is pretty much the same thing, just a legacy mechanism.)
- You can set its source by setting the `src` property, which can be a `file://` URL the user supplies...
- ...or you can let them choose via an `input type="file"` element **if** their browser supports using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/); see [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063) for getting access to image data that way.
- You can put the `img` element in the document by appending it to whatever other element you want to append it to, via [`appendChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107) or related methods.
- You can *find* an existing element using [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId), [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094), etc., or (on most browsers but [not all](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector)) [`querySelector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector) / [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall).

In addition the various specifications linked inline above, you may also find the new work-in-progress [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) useful.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will create an empty image object and it will set its src.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "";
```

We are unable to identify your question & the purpose. please make a jsfiddle with minimum test case. Or explain your question clearly.