# Determine image size in pixels using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to compare image before uploading to be of x by y pixels within file upload control in asp.net
How can I get image size in File Uploader in pixels using javascript?

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the image sizes in javascript is to do the following:

```
var img = document.getElementById('yourimageId'); 

var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

Also have a look at the following answer to a similar previous question:

- [Get Image dimensions using Javascript during file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

in firefox ,you can get the file's path by this method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File.getAsDataURL

or latest version ：

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

for webkit
window.webkitURL.createObjectURL()
see 
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_(DOM)/window.URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/window.URL.createObjectURL)

and set it to a img tag and get the size.
for ie, you shoule set a filter to the elem

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=image)
```

and set the url to this filter then you can get the img's size
good luck