# Can I load a local file into an html canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to have users on iPad load an image into a canvas, then get the base 64 encoded said image all while being **OFFLINE**

### JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm4za/1/)

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        //Get the canvas
        var canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');   

        $("#testButton").click(function(){
          var base_image = new Image();

          base_image.src = $("#testImg").val();
          //base_image.src = '1.jpg';

          //When the image loads
          $(base_image).load(function(){
            //Resize canvas for image
            $("#testCanvas").attr({
              width: base_image.width,
              height: base_image.height
            });

            //Draw image on canvas
            context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);

            //Get base64 encoded image
            var imageString = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            $("#imageString").val(imageString);

            //alert($("#imageString").val().length);
            $("#imageOutput").attr("src", imageString);
          });//image load
        });//Test Button Click
      });//doc ready
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="testImg" id="testImg" />
    </form>
    <button id="testButton">Test</button>
    <canvas id="testCanvas" style="border: 1px solid black;">Your Browser does not support canvas</canvas>
    <br />
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Image Data</legend>
      <textarea id="imageString"></textarea>

      <img id="imageOutput" src="" />
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know the image isn't actually loaded from the `<input type='file' />`, but I figured it was worth a shot. In Chrome console I get:

> Not allowed to load local resource

Is there any way for me to get images from my iPad into a canvas element?

Any help, tips or advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: With JavaScript, it's not possible to access the local filesystem whatsoever.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Any suggestions on how I could accomplish this while being offline?

Comment: I assume you don't want to use an `<input type='file' />`?

Comment: No I do! I don't know any other way to get an iPad to look at it's photos

Comment: Refer to this tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I have a [functioning fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3JtC/4) (based on the prior work of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload/2865063#2865063)) that demonstrates how to upload an image using a file input, place it inside a canvas, and read the base64 data URL back out.

In short, you should:

1. Use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) to read in the image (you might do this in an `onchange` listener of the input element):

```js
var file = input.files[0];
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = createImage;   // onload fires after reading is complete
fr.readAsDataURL(file);    // begin reading
```

2. In your FileReader's `onload` callback (here, `createImage`), read the `result` of the FileReader (here, `fr.result`). That's your image data URL!

**OPTIONAL STEPS** (only needed if you plan to manipulate the images on a canvas):

2. In your FileReader's `onload` callback (here, `createImage`), make a new `Image` object and set its `src` to the `result` of the FileReader:

```js
img = new Image();
img.onload = imageLoaded;
img.src = fr.result;
```

3. Finally, in your Image's `onload` callback, draw it to the canvas and then use `canvas.toDataUrl` to the data:

```js
canvas.width = img.width;      // set canvas size big enough for the image
canvas.height = img.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);         // draw the image

// do some manipulations...

canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  // get the data URL
```

Comment: `fr.readAsDataURL` will set `result` to a data URL so there isn't a need to go through `new Image` and `<canvas>` unless you're planning to edit the image in canvas to get a different output.

Comment: @PaulS. Right, I guess this goes a bit too far! I only did the `canvas` stuff because it was in the OP's original question -- I'll move the extraneous parts to a different section, just in case the OP does want to edit the image after all.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. I tried it on Safari but it does not work. Do you have any tips on that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860782/file-api-not-supported-on-safari-browser

Comment: @AMG If you're using readAsDataURL you don't need an onload callback on the image. As it is loaded immediately. In fact, I found in Firefox that if I had a callback it actually doesn't work.

Comment: I got this message: `Refused to load the image 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ...2Sv/Z' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
`

Comment: @Grim Your site is served with a Content Security Policy and you need to add `data:` to your `default-src` or (much better) add an `img-src` directive with `data:` (plus any other things you use from`default-src` like `'self:`)

Comment: @Grim consider the implications of adding the data: scheme to the CSP before jumping on that solution: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/is-including-the-data-scheme-in-your-content-security-policy-safe/95011#95011

Answer (score 3):

input file, reduce file size with javascript after file upload and pass input file value again.

```js
const input = document.getElementById("img-input");
input.onchange = function (ev) {
  const file    = ev.target.files[0]; // get the file
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const img     = new Image();
  img.src       = blobURL;

  img.onerror = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    // Handle the failure properly
    console.log("Cannot load image");
  };

  img.onload = function () {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    const mime_type = "image/jpeg";
    const quality = qualityRate(file.size);
    const canvas  = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width  = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    const ctx     = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    document.getElementById("root").append(canvas);
    //let data = canvas.toDataURL(mime_type,quality);
    //downloadURI(data, 'stage.jpg');

    canvas.toBlob(blob => {
        let localfile = new File([blob], 'a.jpg',{type:"image/jpeg", lastModified:new Date().getTime()}, 'utf-8');
        let container = new DataTransfer();
        container.items.add(localfile);
        document.querySelector('#img-input').files = container.files;
    },mime_type,quality);
  };
};

function qualityRate(fileSize){
    let QUALITY = 0.5;
    
    if(1000000 > fileSize){
        QUALITY = 0.5;
    }
    else if(3000000 > fileSize){
        QUALITY = 0.7;
    }
    else if(5000000 > fileSize){
        QUALITY = 0.5;
    }
    else if(10000000 > fileSize){
        QUALITY = 0.9;
    }
    else{
        QUALITY = 0.1;
    }
    console.log(QUALITY);
    return QUALITY;
}

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```

```html
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="img-input" type="file" name="fileTest" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="aa">
</form>
<div id="root" style=" display: none; "></div>
```