# How to handle images (from phone) locally without uploading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, image-processing

I am building an app in AngularJS/Javascript, HTML and CSS in a cloud environment (c9.io).

Given this, how do I proceed to create, test an app that takes pictures from the phone album and transforms them (like a filter)? Where do I start and can all of it be done in a cloud environment? Any examples, boilerplates available?

I have come so far that I can manipulate images that are loaded on a server (e.g. `<img source='some/path'>`) 
But how do you handle local images that are not uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an image through `<input type="file">`, then select the file from input's FileList. Let's say you have selected an `input` from DOM. Then you can use File API.

I suggest reading answers here: [Can I load a local file into an html canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938686/can-i-load-a-local-file-into-an-html-canvas-element)