# getImageData gives "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, html, getimagedata

I'm trying to load an image into a canvas, and then get the color data for a pixel that I click on in the image.

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="kartina" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<form>
<input type="text" id="textField">
</form>


var canvas=document.getElementById("kartina");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var textField=document.getElementById("textField");
canvas.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    var x=event.x;
    var y=event.y;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    var p=canvas.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
    textField.value="x: "+x+", y: "+y+", R: "+p[0]+", G: "+p[1]+", B: "+p[2];   
});

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};

img.src="http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/54344main_hh46_47.highres.jpg";

</script>
</html>
```

`getImageData()` produces this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I thought maybe the problem was the cross-domain origin security restrictions, so I tried adding the image loader from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939150/619177):

```
<!--added below the textField form -->
<form action='#' onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type='file' id='imgfile' />
    <input type='button' id='btnLoad' value='Load' onclick='loadImage();' />
</form>

//added below the opening script tag
function loadImage() {
        var input, file, fr, img;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('imgfile');
        if (!input) {
            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = createImage;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function createImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.onload = imageLoaded;
            img.src = fr.result;
        }

        function imageLoaded() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("kartina")
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            var ctxLocal = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctxLocal.drawImage(img,0,0);
            alert(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
        }

        function write(x){
            console.log(x);
        }
}
```

But this gave me the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

[`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData) method should be called on canvas context object:

```
var p = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
```

Comment: ok, that allowed `getImageData` to be executed without the error, but the RGB values are returning "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

As it is written above:

```
var p=ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
```

then right under it:

```
textField.value="x: "+x+", y: "+y+", R: "+p.data[0]+", G: "+p.data[1]+", B: "+p.data[2];
```