# efficient way to check width/height of httppostedfilebase image in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, image, file-upload

On upload of an image file, 
I want to check its width/height.
So far the only way I have found to this is to create an image file out of it either though accessing the memory stream or saving the file o disk, both of which are memory intensive operations.

Perhaps its possible to read the metadata of the file, though I suspect that differences between image types will make this process cumbersome.

Answer (score 9):

```
// File - have type HttpPostedFileBase
var img = Drawing.Image.FromStream(File.InputStream, true, true);
int w = img.Width;
int h = img.Height;
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow! generally we prefer explanation of code to go along with solutions to help with learning. You might take a look at [How to Write A Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there's not a way to do it on the server side without first converting it to an image because the HttpPostedFileBase type could be really any type of file...not just an image.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload) may be solution on the client side though.

Comment: Good idea. I am already showing a preview of the image on the client side using data url, so I have the dimensions available at that time.