# kendo upload image file dimension validation

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

here is my problem i have been using ken do-control upload control to upload my images and the real problem is i want to set validation that user should upload image in 35 mm*45 mm.and in ken do upload events i have given a function `Events(events =>                                                                                         .Select("onImageSelect")`and in function `function onImageSelect(e) {
    if (e.files[0].width == 35||e.files[0].height == 45)
    {
        return true;
    }`
but i am getting width and height undefined

Comment: That's because those properties do not exist on the object you are referencing. [Read this](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/upload#events-select)! Also, you do know that using 35 in your code means 35 __pixels__, not 35mm?

Comment: thnks brett i want user to upload the picture of following dimension 35mm x 45mm and i don't know how to get the image size in mvc or in kendo script

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865017/get-image-dimensions-using-javascript-during-file-upload). Also, you can search for a millimeter to pixel converter online, but to save you the trouble, 35mm ≈ 132px and 45mm ≈ 170px.