# Can KendoUpload limit the dimension of picture?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I need to download images with dimension limitations just like the extension I can do something like this:

```
   upload: function (e) {
            var files = e.files;               
            $.each(files, function () {
                if (this.extension.toLowerCase() != ".jpg") {
                    ShowError('Only jpg are allowed', '');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });               

        },
```

How about in dimension limitations? What am i suppose to do? Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible using kendo upload. See previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076714/kendo-upload-image-file-dimension-validation).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that this component can upload any type of file and not especially picture, there is no feature about that.

If you want to check picture's dimensions, you can do this server-side and return an error if it's invalid or try to find a javascript third-party library that could do this client-side but i don't know if something like that exists.